# How to update props of child to child component

Tags: reactjs

So im trying to pass some props from my login component to the payment component with the user's info, to do this I update as shown below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Login from './login';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import Pay from './payment';
export default class app extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            LoggedInState: false,
            LoggedInUser: [],
            SellingProduct: [],
            Users: [],
            generalproducts: []
        }
    }

render() {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <NavBar logged={this.state.LoggedInUser} />
            <div className="container-fluid">

                <Routes>

                    <Route path='/' element={<HomePage products={this.generalproducts} />} />
                    <Route path='/shoppingcart' element={<ShopCart logged={this.state.LoggedInState} paymentHandle={this.onBuyFromCart} products={this.state.generalproducts} />} />
                    <Route path='/login' element={<Login onLogged={this.onLogInSuccesful} />} />
                    <Route path='/Payment' element={<Pay ProductInProcess={this.state.SellingProduct} user={this.state.LoggedInUser} />} />
                    <Route path='/Camera' element={<Cam />} />
                    <Route path='*' element={<Nomatch />} />

                </Routes>

            </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
}
onBuyFromCart = (prod) => {
    console.log('in');
    this.setState({ SellingProduct: prod });
    console.log('dada');
}
onLogInSuccesful = (userlogged) => {
    this.setState({ LoggedInState: true, LoggedInUser: userlogged });
    console.log('AppLoggedinState', this.state.LoggedInState);
    console.log('AppLoggedinuser', this.state.LoggedInUser);
};
componentDidMount = async () => {
    var response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/products");
    var ConvertedProducts = await response.json();
    this.setState({ generalproducts: ConvertedProducts });
}
```

}

It works fine from login component to the parent component but when payment tab is displayed I get no values using props, for example:

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
export default class Pay extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            productSaled: this.props.ProductInProcess,
            info: [],
            stored: false
        };

    }
    render() {
        return (

     <button className="card p-3" onClick={() => { this.onStoredCardClick(); }}>
                            <div className="img-box">
                                <img src="https://www.freepnglogos.com/uploads/mastercard-png/file-mastercard-logo-svg-wikimedia-commons-4.png"
                                    alt="" />
                            </div>
                            <div className="number">
                                <label className="fw-bold">{this.props.user.CreditCardnum}</label>
                            </div>
                            <div className="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                                <small><span className="fw-bold">Expiry date:</span><span>{this.props.user.CreditCardDate}</span></small>
                                <small><span className="fw-bold">Name:</span><span>{this.props.user.CreditCardName}</span></small>
                            </div>
                        </button>
          );
    }
    onStoredCardClick = () => {
        this.setState({ stored: true });
        console.log('state ', this.state);
        console.log(' props', this.props);
    }
    componentDidMount = () => {

        console.log(this.state);

    }

}
```

gives me nothing as seen here:[payment info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpvfW.png)

And login component is:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { email: "", password: "", message: "" };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h4 className="m-1 p-2 border-bottom">Login</h4>

                {/* Email starts */}
                <div className="form-group form-row">
                    <label className="col-lg-4">Email:</label>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        className="form-control"
                        value={this.state.email}
                        onChange={(event) => {
                            this.setState({ email: event.target.value });
                        }}
                    />
                </div>
                {/* Email ends */}

                {/* Password starts */}
                <div className="form-group form-row">
                    <label className="col-lg-4">Password:</label>
                    <input
                        type="password"
                        className="form-control"
                        value={this.state.password}
                        onChange={(event) => {
                            this.setState({ password: event.target.value });
                        }}
                    />
                </div>
                {/* Password ends */}

                <div className="text-right">
                    {this.state.message}

                    <button className="btn btn-primary m-1" onClick={this.onLoginClick}>
                        Login
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    } //end of render

    //Executes when the user clicks on Login
    onLoginClick = async () => {
        var response = await fetch(
            `http://localhost:5000/users?id=${this.state.email}&password=${this.state.password}`,
            { method: "GET" }
        );

        var body = await response.json();

        if (body.length > 0) {
            //success
            var response = await fetch(
                `http://localhost:5000/users/${this.state.email}`,
                { method: "GET" }
            );
            var body = await response.json();
            console.log(body);
            this.setState({
                message: <span className="text-success">Successfully Logged-in</span>,
            });
            this.props.onLogged(body);
            //window.location = '\payment';

        } else {
            //error
            this.setState({
                message: (
                    <span className="text-danger">Invalid login, please try again</span>
                ),
            });

        }
    };
}
```

this is the console log form [AppState](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMP8n.png)
And this is the console log from [Payment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2j6nb.png)

Comment: I'm curious what the `LoggedInUser` of the app state is. seems like it's initialValue is an empty string `""` but after it's passed into the `Pay` component you are trying to access properties of user as if it's an object

Comment: Well it is meant to be an object, i missdeclareted the string in the state for app, nevertheless i changed it and info won't get to payment component anyway. You made me realize about something so im gonna check the value assignment to see if thats the error

Comment: Yeah I would put a console.log in the render method of the `Pay` component to see what the props coming in are. Could shed some light on the issue, but the problem might be in the Login component

Comment: I checked the value assignment of LoggedInUser, now it does assign an object which is returned by the console log, ill update the question so that you can see its assignment because it still doesn't reach payment component

Comment: So, as seen in the payment props, there's nothing arriving as props just an empty array which i dont understand because the app log shows that 'LoggedInUser' is being updated

Comment: i feel like the body of the response in onLoginClick of the login component is what you want to pass into onLogged to get the user data up to the parents state

Comment: Yes you are right, thanks. I changed it but... the problem is still there haha nothing is reaching payment even like that and if you think about it even with the previous 'onLogged' argument there should be a string being passed to the payment component

Comment: I think I noticed something, for my logs to give me the correct values in parent component i always have to click on the login button 2 times, its the values were not registered in the first render of updating for the parent component, so i thought of setting 'LoggedInUser' as ''x'' by default and it did arrive at payment's state. The question would be, is there any way that I can fix the need of rendering 2 times so that the values will arrive at the first command?

Comment: ah, if you're referring to why the `ttt` and `ddd` logs don't log the updated state, it's because react state updates are asynchronous. if you'd like to perform some action with the new state, you should put it in a callback function as the second argument of setState. 
```
this.setState({ LoggedInState: true, LoggedInUser: userlogged }, () => {
  console.log("ddd", this.state.LoggedInState);
  console.log("ttt", this.state.LoggedInUser);
});```

Comment: i'm still not sure if that solves your issues, i'm sorry i'm not more help. if i were to guess, separating the "LoggedInUser" state into something like userEmail (a string) and userData (object containing card number, expiry date, etc.) might help with the confusion of whether LoggedInUser is a string, object or array

Comment: Don't worry, thank you, ill try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after a couple months I found out that when using `window.locaion`the page will refresh al previous values for the props given, therefore, nothing will arrive to the component being loaded. To prevent this I changed to the usage of `useNavigate` and the hook `useContext` this solved the shortage of arriving information to the other children components. I am not good with the terminology of react yet so excuse for it.

The log in component now look like this (please focus on the useNavigate and useContext as for it is what solved my error):

```
import React, { Component, useState, useContext } from "react";
import { UserContext } from "./UserContext";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";


export default function Login(props) {
    const [State, setState] = useState({
        Email: "",
        password: "",
        message: "",
    });
    const history = useNavigate();

    const [GeneralState, setGeneralState] = useContext(UserContext);
    let onLoginClick = async () => {

        const response1 = await fetch(
            `http://localhost:5000/users?id=${State.Email}&password=${State.password}`,
            { method: "GET" }
        );

        const body1 = await response1.json();

        if (body1.length > 0) {
            //success
            const response = await fetch(
                `http://localhost:5000/users/${State.Email}`,
                { method: "GET" }
            );
            const body = await response.json();

            setState({
                message: <span className="text-success">Successfully Logged-in</span>,
            });

            setGeneralState({
                ...GeneralState,
                LoggedInState: true,
                LoggedInUser: body,
            })
            history("/shoppingcart", { replace: true });

        } else {
            //error
            setState({
                message: (
                    <span className="text-danger">Invalid login, please try again</span>
                ),
            });

        }
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <h4 className="m-1 p-2 border-bottom">Login</h4>

            {/* Email starts */}
            <div className="form-group form-row">
                <label className="col-lg-4">Email:</label>

                <input
                    type="text"
                    className="form-control"
                    value={State.Email}
                    onChange={(event) => {
                        setState({ ...State, Email: event.target.value });

                    }}
                />

            </div>
            {/* Email ends */}

            {/* password starts */}
            <div className="form-group form-row">
                <label className="col-lg-4">password:</label>
                <input
                    type="password"
                    className="form-control"
                    value={State.password}
                    onChange={(event) => {
                        setState({ ...State, password: event.target.value });
                        // console.log(GeneralState)
                    }}
                />
            </div>
            {/* password ends */}
            <div> <a href="/register" style={{ fontSize: 12 }}>No tienes cuenta? Registrate</a></div>

            <div className="text-right">
                {State.message}

                <button className="btn btn-primary m-1" onClick={onLoginClick}>
                    Login
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );


    //Executes when the user clicks on Login

}
```

And the UserContext component, from where useContext takes the info, is this one:

```
import { createContext } from "react";
export const UserContext = createContext();
```

As for the other components like app component, shown in the question statement at the start of this thread, it is necessary to also add the useContext statements so that your whole project will work under the same context.